# Как работает lookbehind в js?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Ожидал, что выражение `/(.)(?<!\1.*)/g` будет выбирать все символы, перед которыми не было таких же. Но почему-то результат всегда `null`.

```js
console.log("12".match(/(.)(?<!\1.*)/g))
```

Comment: Никак не работает. Его там нет

Comment: Вернее есть proposal https://tc39.github.io/proposal-regexp-lookbehind/ и вроде должно работать в хроме

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в хроме давно реализовали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит по той причине, что `.*` может найти пустую строку, а значит выражение `(.)(?<!\1.*)` равноценно `(.)(?<!\1)` и означает "найди любой символ, не равный самому себе".

Используйте `.+`:

```js
console.log("12".match(/(.)(?<!\1.+)/g))
console.log("12".match(/(.)(?<!\1.+)/gs)) // Если нужна поддержка строк с символами перехода на новую строку
```

Блок предварительного просмотра вперёд срабатывает в том месте, где находится текущая позиция. `(.)` находит `1`, сразу после этого происходит проверка, есть ли перед текущей позицией такой же символ, перед которым может быть 1 и более символов, отличных от знаков перехода на новую строку. Т.е. можно представить это так: после того, как найдена `1`, срабатывает `.+`, как в блоке предварительного просмотора вперёд (только тут этот шаблон находит всю подстроку до её начала), а потом движок ищет ближайший к началу строки символ, идентичный захваченному в группе №1. Так как текущая позиция находится сразу после `1`, `.+` не разрешает `\1` найти захваченный символ (так как перед этим идентичным символом должен быть как минимум один символ).

Comment: Т. е. lookbehind работает на подстроке от начала строки по текущий символ включительно и всегда заканчивается на нём?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я добавил описание.